# ¿Cómo reemplazar [(ngModel)] en mi form por que estoy usando el formControlName?

Tags: angular

Tengo el siguiente formulario que es como un ejemplo de Login con dos campos usuario y password.

También cree una clase modelo llamada **Usuario** que contiene esos campos para poder hacer la conexión con mi backend y ya lo hace todo bien, solo que en el navegador me sale el *warning*:

> It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName.
> Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with
> reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed
> in a future version of Angular.

¿Cómo puedo reemplazar en ngModel para obtener el valor de los datos?

Este es mi *HTML*:

```
<form   #lForm="ngForm"  [formGroup]="loginForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-14">
    <div class="row"><label for="user">Usuario</label></div>
    <div class="row"><input type="user" name="user" id="user" class="form-control"  
      formControlName="usuario" [(ngModel)]="usuario.usuario" ></div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-14">
    <div class="row"><label for="password">Password</label></div>
    <div class="row"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control " 
      formControlName="password" [(ngModel)]="usuario.password"></div>
    
  </div>
  
    <div class="row justify-content">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnsize btndark "
        >Aceptar</button>               
    </div>                              
</form>
```

Y mi **`components.ts`**:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  usuario = new Usuario();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, private service:LoginService ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {    

    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      usuario: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })

  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.service.loginUsuario(this.usuario).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate(['/menu']);
        },
        error =>{
          console.log("Datos incorrectos")
        })
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno primero que nada debes borrar los `[(ngModel)]` de tu *HTML* quedando tu código de la siguiente forma:

```
<form   #lForm="ngForm"  [formGroup]="loginForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-14">
        <div class="row"><label for="user">Usuario</label></div>
        <div class="row"><input type="user" name="user" id="user" class="form-control"  
        formControlName="usuario"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-14">
        <div class="row"><label for="password">Password</label></div>
        <div class="row"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control " 
        formControlName="password"></div>   
    </div>
    
    <div class="row justify-content">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnsize btndark "
        >Aceptar</button>               
    </div>
</form>
```

Una vez hecho esto nos vamos al TypeStript donde propongo cambiar un poco el método *onSubmit*, en lugar de usar `this.usuario` simplemente pongas `this.loginForm.value` para recuperar los valores del formulario y ya no utilizar el objeto con el cual hacias el binding antes, tu método *onSubmit* quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
onSubmit() {
  if (this.loginForm.valid) {
    // Aquí cambiarmos this.usuario por this.loginForm.value
    this.service.loginUsuario(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(data => {
      this.router.navigate(['/menu']);
    },
    error =>{
      console.log("Datos incorrectos")
    });
  } 
}
```

Espero te funcione, saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solo eliminalo. `formControlName` se encargará de la asignación que hagas al crear el formulario.

```
  this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      //Agrega los datos en el primer campo. 
      usuario: new FormControl('aqui tus datos', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
```

> Te recomiendo que las validaciones las pongas en un arreglo, asi:
> `usuario: new FormControl('aqui tus datos', [Validators.required]),`
> Para que puedas agregar mas de una.

Comment: a que te refieres con 'aqui tus datos', seria asi  usuario: new FormControl('this.usuario.uuario', Validators.required),

Comment: El `string` que pongas se mostrará en el input, y se capturará en el `loginForm.value`.

Comment: no entendi del todo, probe asi usuario: new FormControl('this.usuario.uuario', Validators.required) pero no funciono, no llego los datos

Comment: Quita las comillas, y si puedes crea en https://www.stackblitz.com un ejemplo con el cual te pueda ayudar.

Comment: ya le quite las comillas pero parece que no los toma, xq cae en  error => del metodo onSubmit

Comment: Edita la pregunta con la traza del error que te da. Es un poco difícil ayudarte con la información que me estas dando.